# Loading Data and Appending without Repetition

Tags: swift, for-loop, parse-platform, tuples

I am currently trying to sort the PFObjects I receive from Parse.com and differentiate them between 'near' and 'far'. So far I am able to place these objects in tuples

var placesID = [(Name: "PlaceName"), (Distance: Double)]

The issue that I am having is the process of differentiating these objects (based on distance) and appending them into separate arrays (nearArray & farArray).

The main problem that I am dealing with is the fact that the tuples are loaded from Parse one at a time. Thereby, the first iteration would be

[(Name: Place A, Distance: 10)]

followed by

[(Name: Place A, Distance: 10), (Name: Place B, Distance: 20)]

and so forth depending on the number of places I have stored in Parse.

Since there are multiple iterations my current method of differentiation the objects through-

```
    for x in self.PlacesID {
                   if x.Distance < 15 {
                   self.nearPlacesID.append(x)       
                    }
                           }
```

does not work as the object with name "Place A" gets iterated multiple times and is able to satisfy the distance constraint. Therefore, the "Place A" gets appended multiple times in the nearPlacesID tuple. I was wondering if there is anyway to have the method wait until all the PFObjects are loaded before it does the differentiates all the objects based on distance. Or if there is any other way to solve the issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

This is the code I have at the moment.

```
var placesID: [(Name: String?, Distance: Double?, Image: UIImage?)] = []

var nearplacelID: [(Name: String?, Distance: Double?, Image: UIImage?)] = []

var farplaceID: [(Name: String?, Distance: Double?, Image: UIImage?)] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    var query = PFQuery(className: "VenueData")

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE.value), 0)){


    let object = query.findObjects() //Get the Object



    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground({ (userLocation: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in //Get User Location
        if let myObject = object as? [PFObject] {




            for x in myObject {
                var name = x.objectForKey("Name") as? String

                var location = x.objectForKey("Location") as? PFGeoPoint
                var distance = location?.distanceInKilometersTo(userLocation)

                var File: PFFile? = x.objectForKey("ImageFile") as? PFFile
                File?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imagedata: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                     var image = UIImage(data:imagedata!)


                self.placesID += [(Name:name, Distance: distance, Image: image)]

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    for x in self.placesID {
                        if x.Distance < 1 {
                         self.nearplaceID.append(x)
                         }
                    }


                    for x in self.placesID {
                        if x.Distance > 1 && x.Distance < 10 {
                            self.farplaceID.append(x)
                        }
                    }


                })

            }


    }


    })


    }
   }
```

Comment: Could you explain how you are getting multiple responses from the Parse server? It would seem to me that you have some code that is storing a response from the server. Why don't you just call the loop after this last storage? It would be helpful if you could show the code so I know what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this  convert your array into NSArray and use containsObject method

```
 for x in self.PlacesID  {
     if !(self.nearPlacesID as NSArray).containsObject(x) { 
          if x.Distance < 15 {
                 self.nearPlacesID.append(x) 
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are having his problem I s because you have a double loop. So every time an object is downloaded, the check if it far or close is run on all of the objects downloaded so far. And each one is checked again. Since you are already in a loop, there is no need to create another one. Just check the one object whether it is close or not.

So, instead, your code should be:

```
if x.distance < 1{
    self.nearPlace.append(x)
}
else if x.distance < 10{
    self.farPlace.append(x)
}
```

(As a note, in your double loop, you use the variable `x` both times as the looping variable. This does not seem very safe, to declare two variable with the same name in the same scope. But nonetheless, there is no need for the inner loops. Replace it with the code above.)